# Adding another foreign key to a table setup in ef core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

I'm working at a .net core project with ef.
I have two tables:

```
    public class Asset
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        
        // Relationships
        public ICollection<AssetMixRecord> AssetMixRecords { get; set; }
    }

    public class AssetMixRecord
    {        
        public decimal Percentage { get; set; }        
        public Guid AssetId { get; set; }

        // Relationships
        public Guid ParentAssetId { get; set; }
    }
```

The context looks like this:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Asset>()
                .HasMany(a => a.AssetMixRecords)
                .WithOne()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            modelBuilder.Entity<AssetMixRecord>()
                .HasKey(c => new { c.ParentAssetId, c.AssetId })
                .IsClustered();
```

The migration code for this looks like:

```
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AssetMixRecords",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    AssetId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                    ParentAssetId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                    Percentage = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(8,7)", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AssetMixRecords", x => new { x.ParentAssetId, x.AssetId })
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Clustered", true);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AssetMixRecords_Assets_AssetId",
                        column: x => x.AssetId,
                        principalTable: "Assets",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });
```

This is all nice and right. But 'ParentAssetId' also is a foreign key to 'Assets.Id'.

Our use case looks like this:

```
var asset1 = new Asset();
            var asset2 = new Asset();

            dbContext.Add(asset1);
            dbContext.Add(asset2);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            var asset3 = new Asset();

            asset3.AssetMixRecords.Add(new AssetMixRecord()
            {
                AssetId = asset1.Id,
                ParentAssetId = asset3.Id
            });

            asset3.AssetMixRecords.Add(new AssetMixRecord()
            {
                AssetId = asset2.Id,
                ParentAssetId = asset3.Id
            });

            dbContext.Add(asset3);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I'm not able to to get this 2nd foreign key into the migration code. Should I just add it manually?

Thanks and regards

S.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out my solution with complete demo, it will generate following migration. I am not sure if it is possible to have `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` with such schema, EF migration tool was complaining about circular dependency.

```
migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
    name: "FK_AssetMixRecords_Assets_AssetId",
    table: "AssetMixRecords");

migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
    name: "FK_AssetMixRecords_Assets_AssetId",
    table: "AssetMixRecords",
    column: "AssetId",
    principalTable: "Assets",
    principalColumn: "Id");

migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
    name: "FK_AssetMixRecords_Assets_ParentAssetId",
    table: "AssetMixRecords",
    column: "ParentAssetId",
    principalTable: "Assets",
    principalColumn: "Id");
```

Demo itself is below. Please notice that there are 2 navigation properties inside `Asset`. EF will load there child entities based on their location (AssetId or ParentAssetId)

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp9
{
    public class Asset
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        // items where AssetMixRecord.AssetId == Id
        public ICollection<AssetMixRecord> AssetMixRecords { get; set; }

        // items where AssetMixRecord.ParentAssetId == Id
        public ICollection<AssetMixRecord> ParentAssetMixRecords { get; set; }
    }

    public class AssetMixRecord
    {
        public decimal Percentage { get; set; }
        public Guid AssetId { get; set; }
        public virtual Asset Asset { get; set; }
        public Guid ParentAssetId { get; set; }
        public virtual Asset ParentAsset { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AssetMixRecord> AssetMixRecords { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=DESKTOP-1111111;Database=testef11db;Integrated Security=true;");

            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Asset>()
                .HasMany(a => a.AssetMixRecords)
                .WithOne(x => x.Asset)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.AssetId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Asset>()
                .HasMany(x => x.ParentAssetMixRecords)
                .WithOne(x => x.ParentAsset)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentAssetId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

            modelBuilder.Entity<AssetMixRecord>()
                .HasKey(c => new { c.ParentAssetId, c.AssetId })
                .IsClustered();

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();

            var asset1 = new Asset();
            var asset2 = new Asset();

            dbContext.Add(asset1);
            dbContext.Add(asset2);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            var assetDataMixRecord = new AssetMixRecord()
            {
                AssetId = asset1.Id,
                ParentAssetId = asset2.Id
            };

            dbContext.Add(assetDataMixRecord);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            var assets = dbContext.Assets
                .Include(x => x.AssetMixRecords)
                .Include(x => x.ParentAssetMixRecords)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

If you do not want to `ParentAssetId` be equal to `ChildAssetId` simply add code below to solution above

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AssetMixRecord>()
    .HasCheckConstraint("PK_Check_ChildAssetId_And_ParentAssetId", "ParentAssetId != ChildAssetId");
```

Your use case will work fine if you change `AssetMixRecords` to `ParentAssetMixRecords` for `asset3`

```
var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
var asset1 = new Asset();
var asset2 = new Asset();

dbContext.Add(asset1);
dbContext.Add(asset2);
dbContext.SaveChanges();

var asset3 = new Asset();

asset3.ParentAssetMixRecords.Add(new AssetMixRecord()
{
    AssetId = asset1.Id,
    ParentAssetId = asset3.Id
});

asset3.ParentAssetMixRecords.Add(new AssetMixRecord()
{
    AssetId = asset2.Id,
    ParentAssetId = asset3.Id
});

dbContext.Add(asset3);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hi Yegor, many thanks for your effort. I got some inspiration from it although it is not quite what I was looking for. For instance this: // items where AssetMixRecord.AssetId == Id, would totally break our use case. This must never happen and we need to avoid it.

Comment: ok, dont forget to post your own solution as an answer

Comment: :-) At the moment a solution seems even more far away: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23071

Comment: To be fair, I am not sure why you think parent asset id should be a foreign key in 
the migration, if it is not mentioned in `OnModelCreating`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your comment. That is part of the question. How to get the two foreign keys into the context definition.

Comment: You posted it as an issue in the github `combined compound key gets overriden`, but it never does, I see compound key is being fine in the migration. Here you say `I'm not able to to get this 2nd foreign key into the migration code` but you never had the code to get it there. I am not following your logic.

Comment: Also I am not sure why you are so strict about my solution, what `use case` is it going to break? you can always build query using db context if you don't like navigation properties

Comment: First my question was, how to get those two foreign key definitions into the context definition and still is (this thread). While I was playing around with it, I discovered that the ChildAssetId get's overwritten by EF when it's defined as foreign key. That led to the other question. Our use case is that a ChildAssetId can never be the same as the ParentAssetId.

Comment: it looks like you did not understand my comment inside code `// items where AssetMixRecord.ChildAssetId == Id`. It means that `Asset.AssetMixRecords` will contain only `AssetMixRecords` where `ChildAssetId` is equal to `Asset.Id`. And `// items where AssetMixRecord.ParentAssetId == Id` means `Asset.ParentAssetMixRecords` will container only items where `ParentAssetId` is equal to `Asset.Id`. It does not imply they can be or can't be equal in child entity

Comment: I added code to cover your case where you do not want ChildAssetId and ParentAssetId be equal

Comment: `HasCheckConstraint` is a nice one. Did not know about it. Further I added code to our use case. What should I put into the `ParentAssetMixRecords` list?

Comment: Ok, correct me if I'm wrong: the navigation property `AssetMixRecords` is not needed but is there only because then one can define the foreign key.

Comment: no, we need both, one for each foreign key inside `AssetMixRecords`

Comment: What I mean by 'not needed' is not needed in the use case but only needed to be able to define the foreign key.

Comment: correct. If you ever want to add items to `asset1` or `asset2`, you will need to use `asset1.AssetMixRecords.Add` instead

Comment: That is plain unacceptable. We cannot step off the use case that far only to get the foreign key in place. ChildAssets need to be added, updated or deleted through one property only.

Comment: ok, just don't forget to post your own solution. Personally I do not think this can be achieved

Comment: even if you define FK in database, entities won't be loaded to your single property

Comment: Thank you again. I definitely took something out of your suggestions. I have a work around right now. My colleagues review it. When we keep it, I will post it.